# Meta Query transform query result into multiple dynamic join of tables and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to transform the result of a query into a dynamic query with multiple JOIN and columns.
Each table have also a common column named "DT" which is the datetime of the row.
About the table which has the responsability about the JOIN (here t1.DT) with the column DT it could be any of them (so it could work with t2.Dt or t3.DT)
I don't care about table order.

The initial matrix (Table, Column, Description) is a result of a previous query that I execute before.

```html
Table   Column  Description
T5165   C25086  01 - Wind direction
T5165   C25182  01 - Nacelle position - degrees
T5165   C25472  02 - Wind direction
T5165   C25568  02 - Nacelle position - degrees
T5165   C25858  03 - Wind direction
T5165   C25954  03 - Nacelle position - degrees
T5165   C26244  04 - Wind direction
T5165   C26340  04 - Nacelle position - degrees
T5165   C26630  05 - Wind direction
T5165   C26726  05 - Nacelle position - degrees
T5165   C27016  06 - Wind direction
T5165   C27112  06 - Nacelle position - degrees
T550    c25250  01 - Unfiltered generator speed
T551    c25636  02 - Unfiltered generator speed
T552    c26022  03 - Unfiltered generator speed
T553    c26408  04 - Unfiltered generator speed
T554    c26794  05 - Unfiltered generator speed
T555    c27180  06 - Unfiltered generator speed
```

So let me show you and example with the 3 first tables. So that is only the beginning of what I want as result but I want to generate this automatically.

```html
SELECT
    TOP 100
    CASE WHEN t1.DT IS NULL THEN 
        CASE WHEN t2.dt IS NULL
            THEN t3.dt
        ELSE 
            t2.dt
        END
    ELSE 
        T1.DT 
    END DT,
    t1.C25086   [01 - Wind direction],
    t1.C25182   [01 - Nacelle position - degrees],
    t1.C25472   [02 - Wind direction],
    t1.C25568   [02 - Nacelle position - degrees],
    t1.C25858   [03 - Wind direction],
    t1.C25954   [03 - Nacelle position - degrees],
    t1.C26244   [04 - Wind direction],
    t1.C26340   [04 - Nacelle position - degrees],
    t1.C26630   [05 - Wind direction],
    t1.C26726   [05 - Nacelle position - degrees],
    t1.C27016   [06 - Wind direction],
    t1.C27112   [06 - Nacelle position - degrees],
    t2.c25250   [01 - Unfiltered generator speed],
    t3.c25636   [02 - Unfiltered generator speed]
FROM
    T5165 t1
FULL JOIN
    T550 t2 ON t2.DT = t1.DT
FULL JOIN
    T551 t3 ON t3.DT = t1.DT
```

So the difficulty is about the number of table and columns are variable and must be determinated at runtime.
I don't want to hardcode the result because there is lot of table and columns in the final result. I just publish a small part of the matrix.

Comment: have you search ed for dynamic sql?

Answer (score 0):

I am very late, you were joining everyting based on the same date, this alone will only get records that has date not null, so there is no need of using `CASE` to check for null, so I only used the date of the first table.

You were joining everything with full join, i found more simple to just add the tables with commas, and then apply where to all of them.

```
--##################################
--######## SOURCE:

CREATE TABLE Temp
(
[Table]   VARCHAR(100),
[Column]  VARCHAR(100),
[Description] VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO Temp VALUES ('T5165',    'C25086',   '01 - Wind direction'),('T5165',    'C25182',   '01 - Nacelle position - degrees'),('T5165',    'C25472',   '02 - Wind direction'),('T5165',    'C25568',   '02 - Nacelle position - degrees'),('T5165',    'C25858',   '03 - Wind direction'),('T5165',    'C25954',   '03 - Nacelle position - degrees'),('T5165',    'C26244',   '04 - Wind direction'),('T5165',    'C26340',   '04 - Nacelle position - degrees'),('T5165',    'C26630',   '05 - Wind direction'),('T5165',    'C26726',   '05 - Nacelle position - degrees'),('T5165',    'C27016',   '06 - Wind direction'),('T5165',    'C27112',   '06 - Nacelle position - degrees'),('T550',     'c25250',   '01 - Unfiltered generator speed'),('T551',     'c25636',   '02 - Unfiltered generator speed'),('T552',     'c26022',   '03 - Unfiltered generator speed'),('T553',     'c26408',   '04 - Unfiltered generator speed'),('T554',     'c26794',   '05 - Unfiltered generator speed'),('T555',     'c27180',   '06 - Unfiltered generator speed')

--##################################
--######## DYNAMIC QUERY:

DECLARE @dateParameter VARCHAR(100) = '2022-01-01'

DECLARE @dateColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 temp.[Table] + '.DT,' FROM temp)

DECLARE @selectColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' SELECT ' + @dateColumn + STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + temp.[Table] + '.' + temp.[Column] + ' ' + QUOTENAME(temp.[Description]) 
            FROM temp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @fromTables AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' FROM ' + STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + temp.[Table]
            FROM temp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @whereDateEquals AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' WHERE ' + STUFF((SELECT distinct ' AND ' + temp.[Table] + '.DT = ''' + @dateParameter + ''''
            FROM temp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,5,'')

EXEC(@selectColumns + @fromTables + @whereDateEquals)
```

In case of you still needing this, tell me if it worked, if you don't need anymore, but found my answer useful, if you could mark my answer as accepted, i would appreciate =D.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answer I did something like you wish using also dynamic sql. So the result is may be dirtier but the job is done.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.get_wind_farm_reporting(
@IdParc INT,
@Debut  DATETIME,
@FIN    DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sqlSelect VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlFrom VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlWhere VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlResult VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sqlOrder VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @strTable VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @strColumn VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @strDescrip VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @intTable INT
DECLARE @intColumn INT
DECLARE @nbTable INT
DECLARE @nbColumn INT
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @j INT = 1
DECLARE @IsFirstTable BIT = 1
DECLARE @IsLastColumn BIT = 0

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#selectedFarm') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #selectedFarm
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#unikTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #unikTable
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#unikColumn') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #unikColumn
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#farmTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #farmTable


SELECT  
    [Txxx (Table)] IdTable, 
     [dbo].get_kerwin_column_name([Txxx (Table)], [Cxxx_1 (Colonne)]) columnName,       
    [Voie Libelle] Descrip 
INTO #selectedFarm
FROM 
    [KERWIN_SQL].[dbo].[get_table_columns_wind_data] ks
WHERE
    ks.IdParc = @IdParc

SELECT DISTINCT IdTable into #farmTable FROM #selectedFarm
SELECT DISTINCT IdTable, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdTable ASC) AS IdRow into #unikTable FROM #farmTable

SELECT @nbTable = count(0) FROM #unikTable

WHILE @i <= @nbTable
BEGIN
    SELECT @intTable = IdTable FROM #unikTable WHERE IdRow = @i
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#unikColumn') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #unikColumn
    SELECT columnName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY columnName ASC) AS IdRow into #unikColumn FROM #selectedFarm WHERE IdTable = @intTable
    SELECT @nbColumn = count(0) FROM #unikColumn
    SET @j = 1
    print 'Table ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @intTable)
    WHILE @j <= @nbColumn
    BEGIN
        SELECT @strColumn = columnName FROM #unikColumn WHERE IdRow = @j
        SELECT @strDescrip = Descrip FROM #selectedFarm WHERE columnName = @strColumn and IdTable = @intTable
        SET @sqlSelect = CASE @IsFirstTable
            WHEN 1 THEN 
                'SELECT
                    t1.DT,'  + ' t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @i) + '.' + @strColumn + ' [' + @strDescrip + ']'
            ELSE
                @sqlSelect + ' t' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @i) +'.'+ @strColumn + ' [' + @strDescrip + ']'
            END         
        IF @i <> @nbTable OR @j <> @nbColumn SET @sqlSelect = @sqlSelect + ','
        SET @j = @j + 1
    END
    SET @sqlFrom = CASE @IsFirstTable WHEN 1 THEN
         ' FROM T' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @intTable) + ' t'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@i)
    ELSE 
        @sqlFrom + ' JOIN T' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @intTable) + ' t'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @i) + ' ON t'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @i) + '.DT = t1.DT' 
    END
    SET @IsFirstTable = 0
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SET @sqlWhere = CONCAT(' WHERE T1.DT BETWEEN ''', dbo.DateString(@Debut), ''' AND ''' , dbo.DateString(@Fin), '''')
SET @sqlOrder = ' ORDER BY T1.DT DESC'

SET @sqlResult = CONCAT(@sqlSelect, @sqlFrom, @sqlWhere, @sqlOrder)
EXEC (@sqlResult)
END
```